# I get an error while executing the below code to make predictions in R

Tags: r

The error  is

> Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") :
> no terms component nor attribute

To the code

```r
cooked2 <- data.frame(cooked = c(1, 3, 6, nrow = 1) )#predicting with 1,3 and 6 times cooking
predict.lm(model2, newdata = cooked2, interval = "prediction")
```

Not able to guess what  is the issue, since in another code it worked.

Works here

```r
ig1 <- data.frame(ig = c(10, 100, 200)) #predicting with 10,100 and 200 followers
predict.lm(model, newdata = ig1)  #predicting with lm since we use lm models in TASK 1
```

Edit : Model 2 is created by

cor(dw$wb, dw$cooked)  #predic ting with the variable cooked

#the result is 0.6047707 which shows the variables are close to postively correlated.

#Now with the help of lm( ) function, we are going to make a linear model.
#lm( ) function has two attributes first is a formula where we will use “ wb~ cooked”
#because cooked is an independent variable and wb is a dependent variable
r

```r
model2 <- lm(wb ~ cooked, data = dw)
print(model2)
summary(model2)
```

Comment: I removed nrow still getting the same error, is there any way to use upper and lower limit here?

Comment: How did you make "model2"? Please edit your question to allow us to replicate the issue, e.g. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) / [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Worth noting that `vector` is neither `matrix` nor `data.frame`, and none of your examples point towards `vector(mode = 'numeric & etc'`, so you might, for clarity, drop vector from title, unless of course it is a vector you want, in which case, drop data.frame and nrow...

Comment: @jared_mamrot, edited with model 2

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info provided, please test:

```
model2 <- lm(wb ~ cooked, data = dw)
cooked2 <- data.frame(cooked = c(1, 3, 6))
predict(model2, newdata = cooked2)
predict(model2, newdata = cooked2, interval = "prediction")
```

Do these return the same error?

Comment: Turns out I set model 2 as a variable in creating a ggplot too, that was causing an issue, thanks for pointing out the problem can be in using model 2